# Segmented Control not affecting if loop in -(IBaction) method

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol, ibaction

I am making an IOS app which plays wav files on the press of a UIButton. I am attempting to implement a UISegmentedcontrol, in order to change which sample is being played when a different segment is highlighted.

Here is my code for my viewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
-(IBAction)playFile1;
-(IBAction)playFile2;
-(IBAction)playFile3;
@end
```

and viewController.m

```
@synthesize segmentedControl = segmentedControl;
-(IBAction)playFile1{
    if([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0){
    [rtcmixmanager playFile1];
    }
    else if([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 1){
    [rtcmixManager playFile2];
    }
    else{
    [rtcmixManager playFile3];
    }
}
```

I have tried both this method, and adding a similar if statement in the RTCMixManager.m file under the -(IBaction) method itself, with no luck. 
The project will compile but it seems to only play file 1, no matter which segment is highlited. does anyone know why this is?

Comment: My guess is that you connected the action to the wrong event of the segmentedControl. Have you connected it to the "Value Changed" event?

Comment: i'm not sure how to connect the event? i'm kind of new to objective c, from my understanding i could use a conditional statement with the segmented index selection, without having any connections from the view controller.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. Your conditional statement is fine, but you need to connect the outlet (in you case the segmented control) to the action (the IBAction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segControl = ((UISegmentedControl *)sender);
    if([segControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0){
        [rtcmixmanager playFile1];
    }else if([segControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 1){
        [rtcmixManager playFile2];
    }else{
        [rtcmixManager playFile3];
    }
}
```

And connect it to the "value changed" of the Segmented Control event in the .xib file

Edit:
You can also do it in code like this:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: I tried this, i made sure to add -(IBAction)segmentedChanged; to the .h file as well, and connected the Value Changed of my view to the file's owner's segmentedChanged value.. now when i run the app, it closes itself when i try to press the button, it also closes itself when i try to press any of the segmented button.

Comment: Well then, you should look in the debug console for the exception that you get.

Comment: i get this in the debugging window if i press a button '2012-12-12  -[RTAudioFileViewController playFile1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x593bbb0
 RTAudioFile[533:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RTAudioFileViewController playFile1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x593bbb0''


                                                                   and this if i press the segmented control: 'RTAudioFile[546:207] -[RTAudioFileViewController segmentedChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e3ad10'

Comment: Well then, your segment works fine now. The object that you send the message to (rtcmixManager) does not recognize the selector. Make sure to have the method in the interface file of class of this object(that is the .h file) and have it implemented in the .m file. You should accept my answer since the segmented control problem is now fixed. Good luck.

Comment: the method is "segmentChanged:" not "segmentedChanged"

Comment: The application is still crashing when i either press the segmented control, or press the button which triggers the sample. I added this to RTCMixManager.h "@property (nonatomic, retained) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedChanged;" and i added this to RTCMixmanager.m: "@synthesize segmentedChanged"

Comment: and just changed the code to say "segmentChanged", but the same crash is occuring

Comment: the action is called "segmentChanged:" keep in mind you should add the ":" in the name in the @selector(segmentChanged). Your outlet is called "segmentedControl", not "segmentedChanged". It should be "@property (nonatomic, retained) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;"

Comment: okay, this has fixed the crashing problem, but now it is only playing the File 1 sound clip, no matter which segment i have highlited. I tried switching the contional statement to the RTCmix manager, and still run into the same issue.